# error on include gem 'shoppe'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Im trying to setup shoppe according to their manual at: [tryshoppe.com](http://tryshoppe.com/docs/tutorials/getting-started)

Therefor I am using Rails 4.0.1 with ruby 2.0.0p643 on rvm.

On the gerenation of shoppe:setup, or just 'rails c' I get following error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'shoppe'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
  from /tmp/foo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:60:in `require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:60:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
  from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I don't get it. I've although tried this with ruby 2.2 and newer rails, leading to the same error.

This is the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'shoppe'

gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Comment: have you confirmed with when you cd into the project folder, proper version of ruby gets loaded. Try using a gemset and use .rvmrc to load proper setup. nvr used shoppe so can't say any issue with gem loading specific

Comment: try like this using `bundle exec rake db:migrate shoppe:setup `

Comment: its failing with: `Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'shoppe'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the latest pre-release or release candidate version for Bundler (via `gem install bundler --pre`), it should have this change in it: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/4187

This change should allow you to see the original error context instead of just the generic, unhelpful `Bundler::GemRequireError`.

Comment: Actually that was it! thanks very much. My Problem was `Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime.` I could see it thourgh your fix.